# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'oracleCreate'?

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error I've done the same thing for the other SQLite class and it works fine. With the Oracle class it has holdups. Mostly I just can't seem to figure out why there's an error in my own class when I know the class is there. Thanks in advance for any help.

createClass.py

```
from tkinter import *

import MainClass
import SQLiteCreate
import oracleCreate


class createClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def createpage(self):
        def quit():
            window.destroy()
        
        def oracleCreate():
            quit()
            obj = oracleCreate.oracleCreate()
            obj.createpage()

        def mongoCreate():
            pass

        def sqliteCreate():
            quit()
            obj = SQLiteCreate.sqliteCreate()
            obj.createpage()

        def back():
            quit()
            obj = MainClass.main_project()
            obj.mainpage()

        window = Tk()
        window.geometry("600x300")
        window.title("DATA WORLD")
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        #header, content, footer
        header = Frame(window, bg='dark gray')
        header.grid(row=0, sticky='news')

        content = Frame(window, bg='black')
        content.grid(row=1, sticky='news')

        footer = Frame(window, bg='dark gray')
        footer.grid(row=2, sticky='news')

        window.columnconfigure(0, weight=5)

        window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        window.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)
        window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        welcome = Label(header, text="Table Creator", bg='dark gray')
        welcome.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        welcome.pack()
        oracle_but = Button(content, text="Oracle", command=oracleCreate,width=15, height=2)
        oracle_but.place(x=75, y=40)
        mongo_but = Button(content, text="MongoDB", command=mongoCreate,width=15, height=2)
        mongo_but.place(x=375, y=40)
        sqlite_but = Button(content, text="SQLite", command=sqliteCreate,width=15, height=2)
        sqlite_but.place(x=225, y=40)
        back_but = Button(content, text='Back', command=back, width=15, height=2)
        back_but.place(x=225, y=100)
        

        #Run Window
        window.mainloop()
```

oracleCreate.py

```
from tkinter import *

import cx_Oracle
import DBconnect
import createClass

class oracleCreate():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def createpage(self):
        def quit():
            window.destroy()

        def createTable():
            try:
                obj = DBconnect.SQLiteDB()
                obj.create(tableName.get(), tableCols.get())
                top= Toplevel(window)
                top.geometry("500x200")
                top.title("Success")
                Label(top, text= "Table Created Successfully").place(x=150,y=80)
            except cx_Oracle.OperationalError as e:
                    top= Toplevel(window)
                    top.geometry("500x200")
                    top.title("Failed")
                    Label(top, text= "The table you attempted to create already exists please try another name or use another operation.", font='Arial 8').place(x=0,y=80)
                    print(e)

        def back():
            quit()
            obj = createClass.createClass()
            obj.createpage()


        window = Tk()
        window.geometry("600x300")
        window.title("DATA WORLD")
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        #Page Format
        header = Frame(window, bg='dark gray')
        header.grid(row=0, sticky='news')

        content = Frame(window, bg='black')
        content.grid(row=1, sticky='news')

        footer = Frame(window, bg='dark gray')
        footer.grid(row=2, sticky='news')

        window.columnconfigure(0, weight=5)

        window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        window.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)
        window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        welcome = Label(header, text="Data World", bg='dark gray')
        welcome.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        welcome.pack()
        
        #Entry boxes
        tableName = Entry(window, width=60)
        tableName.place(x=50, y=125)
        tableCols = Entry(window, width=60)
        tableCols.place(x=50, y=175)

        #Labels
        Label(window, text="Table Name: ", fg='white', bg='black').place(x=50, y=100)
        Label(window, text="Table Columns and types seperated by comma: ", fg='white', bg='black').place(x=50, y=150)

        #Buttons
        submit_but = Button(window, text='Submit', command=createTable, width=15)
        submit_but.place(x=50, y=200)
        back_but = Button(window, text='Back', command=back, width=15)
        back_but.place(x=200, y=200)

        window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have used `oracleCreate` as a function name.  Rename the function.

Comment: Just some general advice: in classes, it's a good idea not to define any functions inside each other. Functions should be named in `snake_case`, so `oracleCreate` would be `oracle_create`. And any variables that are going to be used throughout the class should be prefixed with `self.` So `self.window`, `self.footer`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a module named `oracleCreate`, but then inside your `createPage()` method you define a function named `oracleCreate`.  Within the scope of your `createPage()` method, this replaces the module you've imported with your function.  So when `oracleCreate.oracleCreate()` executes, Python tries to access an attribute named `oracleCreate` of your `oracleCreate` function.  This of course doesn't exist, hence the error you get.

You don't have the same problem with SQLite because the module is named `SQLiteCreate` and you declare a function named `sqliteCreate` inside `createPage()`.

Rename either your `oracleCreate` module or your `oracleCreate` function.